# how to pass a previous argument in a recursion

Tags: c, function, recursion

I wonder if it is possible in a recursion to pass an argument from the previous calling function.

Can I use return to succeed this?

For example in the new recursion I wand to keep the previous string.

Comment: Could you please give an example on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to post some practical stuff that represents what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you give an example? Recursion often _requires_ that you pass an argument from the previous function.

Comment: Do you mean being able to access the previous value and the one before that? (Like in the Fibonacci sequence where the next value depends on the previous two values)

Answer (score 2):

While being uncleared from your question, you can obviously pass *an argument(s) from the previous calling function* while using a recursive function.

[From wikipedia arcticles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

> Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way. For
>   instance, when the surfaces of two mirrors are exactly parallel with
>   each other the nested images that occur are a form of infinite
>   recursion. The term has a variety of meanings specific to a variety of
>   disciplines ranging from linguistics to logic. The most common
>   application of recursion is in mathematics and computer science, in
>   which it refers to a method of defining functions in which the
>   function being defined is applied within its own definition.
>   Specifically this defines an infinite number of instances (function
>   values), using a finite expression that for some instances may refer
>   to other instances, but in such a way that no loop or infinite chain
>   of references can occur. The term is also used more generally to
>   describe a process of repeating objects in a self-similar way.

**Examples**

• Towers of Hanoi

• Writing Linked Lists Backwards

• Recursive Insert

• 8 Queens

• Recognizing Simple Languages

• Prefix Expressions

• Conversion Prefix to Postfix

---

Simple example that recursively calculates the factorials of a number.

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) 
{
     if (n <= 1) 
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

The function calls itself recursively on a smaller version of the input (n - 1) and multiplies the result of the recursive call by n, until reaching the base case, analogously to the mathematical definition of factorial.

*While using a recursive function, you always need to break that function explicitly by imposing some mechanisms like an `if` condition within the function otherwise the call will never return.*

Answer (score 1):

```
void recursive(int* data)
{
   //TODO: do something useful, for now just increment by one;
   *data+=1;

   if (*data>99)
   {
     return;
   }
   else
   { 
    recursive(data);
   }   
}
```

Comment: This function will **never** return and will get stuck into an infinite loop, since there is no any **breaking** condition within the function.